# Hibernate cannot close connection for Postgresql

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, connection, c3p0

I am using a heroku remote PostgreSQL database, and in my application, I also use hibernate and c3p0. Already set max connection, and close connection after use, but all of these failed to close idle connection in database. Errors in my code? Since if I only change url and connect to a local MySQL, it works. So I am thinking PostgreSQL is special. Or it is because the heroku remote db restriction?

hibernate.cfg.xml is like this. I change it to adapt local mysql, and it does close connections.

```
<session-factory>

    <!-- hibernate connection configuration -->
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/website</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>

    <!-- hibernate performance configuration -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- c3p0 configuration -->
    <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">10</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_statements">3</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">2</property>
    <property name="c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">90</property>
    <property name="transaction.auto_close_session">true</property>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod">60</property>
    <property name="maxIdleTime">30</property>





    <!-- presistance objects -->
    <mapping class="pojo.WebSiteCommentPOJO"/>

</session-factory>
```

HibernateUtil is like this:

```
    public class HibernateUtils {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory != null) {
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure();

    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();

    serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(conf.getProperties());

    /*ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();*/

    SessionFactory sf = conf.buildSessionFactory();
    return sf;
}

public static Session getSession() {
    return getSessionFactory().openSession();
}
```

}

And the following code is how I use hibernate.

```
public WebSiteComment getSingle(int id) {
    Session ss = HibernateUtils.getSession();
    ss.beginTransaction();
    WebSiteCommentPOJO w = ss.get(WebSiteCommentPOJO.class,id);
    ss.getTransaction().commit();

    return new WebSiteComment(w.getId(), w.getComment(), w.getEmail(), w.getDate());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the `session` to close a connection. When transaction is committed session and connection are not closed because of you can begin a new transaction or do something else with a session. Probable, MySQL have a large number of connections that can be opened. Heroku, of course, has a limited number of connections.

Use `finally` block to close the `session` in any way. You can use [this](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/factory/HibernateSessionFactory.java#L41) pattern to work with a session.

Just do this to configure a session factory

`SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();`

And you need to rollback transaction in case of error.

**Update**

My answer, probably, is not very correct because of using

`<property name="transaction.auto_close_session">true</property>`

Comment: @Alvin In the simplest case use `getSession()`. Please, add code with `close` to your question.

Comment: Since I use `ss.beginTransaction();` and `ss.getTransaction().commit();`, they will close session for me. BTW, the same code works for a local MySQL.

Comment: @Alvin Sorry. Looks like, connection is closed because of `<property name="transaction.auto_close_session">true</property>`. But try to close it manually.

Comment: And also the max_size of connection pool does' work either

Comment: @Alvin I again miss that you use `hibernate.cfg.xml`. Does closing the session  manually  help?

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Doesn't work :-(     Spend the whole night on this. To speed up connection, I set <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property> Don't know whether it matters. Gonna try it morning

Comment: @Alvin You are welcome. But, sorry, I can't help you a lot. Try to remove all unnecessary stuff like `<property name="transaction.auto_close_session">true</property>` and do things manually.

Comment: is the issue maybe that you experience failures over the network that you don't experience locally? for example, in the code above, if there was an Exception anywhere after `Session ss = HibernateUtils.getSession();` but before completion of `ss.getTransaction().commit();`, the Session wouldn't auto_close and you'd leak the Connection. maybe ensure that the transaction is always resolved via a finally block.

Comment: @SteveWaldman It is a good assumption. May be need to log exceptions properly.

Comment: Hey. bro, I fixed it! Changed a little bit to HibernateUtils! I will share my solutions. Again thx for your kindly help, especially your fast reply in late midnight!

Comment: @Alvin You are welcome. But I don't see an essential difference between versions of `HibernateUtils`. It is strange. Maybe you use it in the different way.

Comment: Sometimes code is amazing like this, don't know why bugs appear, how disappear :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed my errors. I found a standard `HibernateUtil.java` from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-tutorial-web/3.3.1.GA/org/hibernate/tutorial/util/HibernateUtil.java) Now my code is like this.

```
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
return sessionFactory;
}
```

The crucial difference maybe the `final` of `sessionFactory`; But I think in my previous version, after initialization, I still return the same sessionFactory object.
Besides, I use some different method to get `SessionFactory`.

Spend 2 days on this, and thanks v.ladynev's help. Hope my solution will help.