# Postgres connections not closing -Hibernnate ererereq

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I am using PostgreSQL for my Web Application. I have put `session. close` in each hibernate call in Web app code. But postgreSQL connections are not closing which makes the application break after the connection count reaches the  threshold. I need to restart my PostgreSQL service to get it up again.

I am using Apache tomcat as webserver.

How can I solve this weirdness? Please suggest a permanent fix.

**code snippet :**

```
try {

    session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

} finally {  
    if (session != null) {  
        session.close();
    }    
}
```

**Hibernate Config file:**

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">auto</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">on_close</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider">com.myapp.connections.MultiTenantConnectionsProvider </prop>
<prop key="hibernate.multiTenancy">DATABASE</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver">com.myapp.connections.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver </prop>
</props>
</property>
```

**Getting below error :**

```
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to instantiate specified multi-tenant connection provider
```

Please help. Been badly stuck with this

Comment: Can you check     <property name="transaction.auto_close_session">true</property>
in your config file ?

Comment: @ Dhiral , Can you please tell me which config file - Hibernate or Postgres?

Comment: check with hibernate config.

Comment: Tried but no luck. Have updated my config file for hib. Please check and advise

Comment: I found one answer already answered. Please check if its help:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618621/hibernate-cannot-close-connection-for-postgresql